# What is the fastest way to load an image from SD card into a view

Tags: android, performance, image, load

I want to implement a picture gallery and I'm not satisfied with the performance of my solution. My application creates small thumbnails (around 1k file size / 64x64px) and stores them onto SD card.
Loading these images from SD card into a view costs some time (20ms per thumbnail) and causes that the gallery does not scroll very smooth.

I've tried loading the image using BitmapFactory.decodeStream or BitmapDrawable(InputStream). I don't want a full memory cache, because - depends on the number of pictures - OutOfMemory can occour and the initial creation of the cache tasks a lot of time.

Has anybody an idea how to load the images in a faster way? Are the framworks for free? Or or or...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read "[File I/O and efficiency](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7d61ca0fb8ec15ae)" post on Android Google groups. After the benchmarks author came to the conclusion that the most efficient way of file I/O is `"batch operation on a memory mapped ByteBuffer"`.

In your case it may be more efficient to use one big file for thumbnails storage instead of hundreds of small ones. You may also need a separate file for indexing (e.g. for mapping between file name/number and start/end position in big thumbnail file) - this however depends on your logic.

Comment: I will try, but this will take some time.